# SQL: Get Last date in a series of dates

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with dates and a column that tells if it's the first date in a series of dates that are "connected".
Example

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦═══════╗
║ person_id ║    DATE    ║ FIRST ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬═══════╣
║         1 ║ 2013-05-31 ║     1 ║
║         1 ║ 2013-06-01 ║     0 ║
║         1 ║ 2013-06-02 ║     0 ║
║        15 ║ 2013-07-08 ║     1 ║
║        15 ║ 2013-07-09 ║     0 ║
║         1 ║ 2013-07-30 ║     1 ║
║         1 ║ 2013-07-31 ║     0 ║
║         1 ║ 2013-08-01 ║     0 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩═══════╝
```

I need a new table that consists of a column for start date and end date for each series. Example:

```
╔═══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ person_id ║ START_DATE ║  END_DATE  ║
╠═══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║         1 ║ 2013-05-31 ║ 2013-06-02 ║
║        15 ║ 2013-07-08 ║ 2013-07-09 ║
║         1 ║ 2013-07-30 ║ 2013-08-01 ║
╚═══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Is it possible without using a while-loop?
I tried a while-loop like but it's to slow. The table is around 100 000 records.

The loop I tried looked something like below:

```sql
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('dbo.temp_table'))
drop table temp_table;
go

SELECT
[person_id],
[date],
[first],
0 AS Processed,
N = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p_id, datum)
INTO temp_table
FROM [person_dates]
ORDER BY person_id, date
go

declare @N int
declare @N2 int
declare @P_ID int
declare @DATE varchar(10)
declare @DATE2 varchar(10)
declare @start_date datetime
declare @end_date datetime

While (Select Count(*) From temp_table Where Processed = 0 AND first=1) > 0 
Begin 
    Select @N=N,@P_ID=person_id, @DATE=date From temp_table Where Processed = 0 AND first=1 ORDER BY N
    set @start_date = CAST(@DATE as datetime)
    set @DATE2=@DATE
    while (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_table Where Processed = 0 AND first<>1 and 
           CAST(date as datetime) = dateadd(day,1,CAST(@DATE2 as datetime)) and person_id=@P_ID) > 0
    Begin
        Select @N2=N,@DATE2=date From temp_table Where Processed = 0 AND first<>1 and 
           CAST(date as datetime) = dateadd(day,1,CAST(DATE2 as datetime)) and person_id=@P_ID ORDER BY N
        Update temp_table Set Processed = 1 Where N = @N2    
    End
    set @end_date=CAST(@DATE2 as datetime)
    Update temp_table Set Processed = 1 Where N = @N
End
go

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('dbo.temp_table'))
drop table temp_table;
go
```

Comment: Why there are two rows with `person_id = 1` in the result set?

Comment: What DBMS? SQL Server?

Comment: @AndreyGordeev - yes exactly how is one to determine if end date 08-01 corresponds with 07-30 or 05-31?

Comment: Perhaps add a check to ensure the end date precedes all other "first" dates for the given person_id -- but if overlapping sets are allowed then that wouldn't work and I don't think there is really enough info in the table to resolve the issue.

Comment: Each person can have N number of date series. The only way to know if they are connected are if the next rows date is last rows date+1 (if the rows have the same person_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple observation.  If you do a cumulative sum of the "first" column, then you will have a column that defines each group.

In some databases, you can do a cumulative sum by using window/analytic functions.  In others, you need a correlated subquery.

```
select person_id, min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date
from (select pd.*,
             (select sum(first)
              from person_dates pd2
              where pd2.person_id = pd.person_id and
                    pd2.date <= pd.date
             ) as cumfirst
      from person_dates pd
     ) pd
group by person_id, cumfirst;
```

Using the ANSI standard cumulative sum syntax, you can write this as:

```
select person_id, min(date) as start_date, max(date) as end_date
from (select pd.*,
             sum(first) over (partition by person_id order by date) as cumFirst
      from person_dates pd
     ) pd
group by person_id, cumfirst;
```

Comment: The first one (with sub query) worked like a charm in MS SQL.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a single SQL statement, using a self join,

```
Select distinct person_id, s.Date startDate, 
   e.Date endDate
From person_dates s
  Left Join n -- find next first if one exists
     On n.person_id = s.person_id           
        And First = 1
        And n.Date = 
           (Select Min(date) from person_dates 
            Where person_id = s.person_id
               And First = 1
               And date > s.Date)
  Join person_dates e -- find last row before next first
     On e.person_id = s.person_id
        And e.Date =
            (Select Max(date) from person_dates 
             where person_id = s.person_id
                And date > s.Date 
                And date < Coalesce(n.Date, date+1))
Where s.First = 1
```